# Is it usable to install ubuntu over laptop Dell Latitude E5420 already installed with Windows 8.1?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell, performance

I am using Windows 8.1 on Dell Latitude E5420 and I am interested to give a try to Ubuntu. So to use Ubuntu efficiently, whether would I need to remove Windows and then install Ubuntu or can install Ubuntu without removing Windows so that I don't get slower performance on both OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to install ubuntu on a virtual machine and get use to it. Once you feel comfortable using ubuntu make the partition of your disk or even better reboot your computer with only ubuntu :D

https://www.virtualbox.org/
http://www.ubuntu.com/

Hope that helps